# matlab array elements that meet a condition no loop

Tags: matlab, vectorization, logical-operators

I have an array of elements and 2 other arrays
I'm doing something like this:

```
a=[1 3 2 45 4 23 16];
b=[3 9 1 27 33 50 5];
m=10;
k=linspace(min(a),max(a),m);
res=zeros(m,1);
for i=1:m
    res(i) = sum((a < k(i)).*(b < k(i)));
end
```

Is there any way to get the same result with no loops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove the loop, you can use `bsxfun`, keeping the rest of your script:

```
res = sum(bsxfun(@lt,a',k).*bsxfun(@lt,b',k),1).';
```

Basically, it applies the operator less-than to the pairs of vectors (a,k) and (b,k); the transposition guarantees that you compare a column vector to a row one, leading to a matrix result. The reduction of the dot product is made along a specified direction (row direction). I transpose the result to have the same size as yours, but it is not mandatory.

Comment: and here goes the `bsxfun`!

Comment: @Divakar I have to confess, I'm a big fan of this awesome function :)

Comment: @Bentoy13 and I am fan of those fans ;) You had my +1 just because of that!

Comment: This is nice but impossible to read for someone not familiar with matlab

Comment: @jucestain I admit that this is not straightforward to understand for a beginner. However, I think that parentheses help a lot to slice the formula into shorter understandable pieces, and if you understand the purpose of bsxfun, you can catch it. And also, that's why I've tried to explain the solution -- I can expand it if you think that it's not clear).

Comment: @Bentoy13 It's fine. With proper commenting it'll be pretty clear. I just feel a little weird toward `bsxfun` but I guess that's more of a personal thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `repmat`:

```
a=[1 3 2 45 4 23 16];
b=[3 9 1 27 33 50 5];
m=10;
k=linspace(min(a),max(a),m);
for i=1:m
    res(i) = sum((a < k(i)).*(b < k(i)));
end
k=transpose(k);
k=repmat(k,[1,7]);
a=repmat(a,[m,1]);
b=repmat(b,[m,1]);
res2 = sum((a<k).*(b<k),2);
```

Note that `res2=transpose(res)`